# Why is a user not authenticated if exists, but is disabled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to implement an exception that denies access to a user if it is disabled, but it doesn't show me the error message that the user is disabled when the disabled user logs in.

The wrong credentials message is displayed successfully if they were entered incorrectly, but the disabled user error is not displayed.

I am managing the enabled user field with a **Boolean** and although it is false, that is, disabled user, Spring does not show the error.

I should mention that I am using the latest versions of both Spring Boot and the dependencies.

When I enter the credentials of a disabled user I receive this error in the console:

```
ERROR [0;39m [35m24932 [0;39m [2m--- [0;39m [2m[nio-8080 -exec-8] [0;39m [36mw.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m: [0;39m An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
```

Here my code:

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class loginController {

// CHECK IF THE USER IS AUTHENTICATED
    private boolean authenticacion() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || AnonymousAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        return authentication.isAuthenticated();
    }

    // SHOWS THE LOGIN SECTION
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String soppLoginPage(@RequestParam(name = "error", required = false) String error, Model model) {
            if (error != null) {
                if ("inactiveUser".equals(error)) {                 
                    model.addAttribute("inactiveUser", "Disabled User");
                } else  {
                    model.addAttribute("badCredentials", "Bad Credentials");
                }
            }
        
        // CHECK IF THE USER IS ALREADY LOGGED IN
        if (authenticacion()) {
            return "redirect:/home";
        }
        
        return "login";
    }
```

}

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepositorio userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad credentials");
        }
        

        if (!user.getEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException("Inactive user");
        }

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
      httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
              .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(
              "/login**")
              .permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/login")
              .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
              .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
              .permitAll()
          .and()
          .logout()
              .invalidateHttpSession(true)
              .clearAuthentication(true)
              .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
              .logoutSuccessHandler(authenticationLogoutHandler)
              .permitAll();

      return httpSecurity.build();
  }
  
  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
  
  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
  
  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationLogoutHandler authenticationLogoutHandler;
```

**AuthenticationFailureHandler**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("A user has failed to login. Error: " + exception.getMessage());

        if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            // SET IF USER IS DISABLED
            super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=inactiveUser");
        } else {
            // SET IF BAD CREDENTIALS
            super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=badCredentials");
        }
        
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(name = "user", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String user;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private Boolean enabled;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

**HTML Error Messages/Thymeleaf**

```
<div th:if="${badCredentials}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <span th:text="${badCredentials}"></span>
                </div>
                
                <div th:if="${inactiveUser}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <span th:text="${inactiveUser}"></span>
                </div>
                
                <div th:if=${param.logout}>
                    <div class="alert alert-info">Ha cerrado sesión exitosamente</div>
                </div>
```

**UserRepository**

```
public interface UsuarioRepositorio extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.user= ?1 AND u.enabled= False")
    public User findByUsername(String user);
    
}
```

Any suggestions to add or fix my code?

Comment: Can you please show the complete error message? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Sure, the error that the console shows me is the following: 2023-09-27T16:42:22.415-06:00 [0;39m [31mERROR [0;39m [35m24932 [0;39m [2m-- - [0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-6] [0;39m [36mw.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m: [0;39m An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Disabled user

Supposedly everything is correct, but I don't know why it doesn't display the error message that the user is disabled.

Comment: What is shown to the user?

Comment: It does not show the user any error message, nor does it even show the /login?error=inactiveUser parameter in the URL.

Comment: You shouldn't expose this information from a security perspective. Why? It gives hackers the information that 1. it is a correct user, 2. it had a correct password 3. the user was disabled. You don't want to give out that information. That being said your query already does the filtering where you should let Spring Security do that (which it already does if you return the regular `User` from Spring Security, or implement `UserDetails` in your `User` class).

Comment: Is your `onAuthenticationFailure` method being called? Can you check with a debugger?